# What is the best way to get a list of video modes and find a specific mode inside assembly? Osdev

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-16, osdev

I am trying to write an OS, currently, I have a bootloader that enables the A20 line and loads the second stage bootloader in which I aim to get the video mode set and give the control to the C kernel.

It is all 16 bit and I have yet to give control to the C kernel so all the code must be written in assembly. I call `ax=4f00 int 10` to get the vbe information then I try to print the list of video modes using the following code

```
; Video List ------------------------------------------------------;
ListModes:                                                         ;
    mov ecx, 0                                                     ;
.loop1:                                                            ;
                                                                   ;
    mov ax, vbe_info_structure+0x0E                                ;
    add ax, cx                                                     ;
    mov bx, ax                                                     ;
    push word [bx]                                                 ;
    call print_hex_word                                            ;
    add ecx, 1                                                     ;
                                                                   ;
    cmp word [bx], 0xFFFF                                          ;
    je .done                                                       ;
                                                                   ; 
    jmp .loop1                                                     ;
.done:                                                             ;
    mov bx, done_msg                                               ;
    call print_string                                              ;
    ret                                                            ;
;------------------------------------------------------------------;
```

I also made it so that `print_hex_word` also prints a space character so I can read the output. Using this function I get the following output:

[image: Output]

I have three questions:

1. Is the output the list I am looking for? If not, what is wrong with the code?
2. Is there a better/faster/more efficient way to achieve this, if there is any?
3. How can I receive detailed information about each of these modes? Is there a shortcut besides using `ax=4f01 int 10h`?

- 

Edit:

After pointed out by Margaret Bloom I changed the code to the following and I saw the good old familiar list of video modes.

```
; Video List ------------------------------------------------------;
ListModes:                                                         ;
                                                                   ;
    mov ecx, 0                                                     ;
.loop1:                                                            ;
                                                                   ;
    mov ax, vbe_info_structure+0x0E                                ;
    add ax, cx                                                     ;
    mov bx, ax                                                     ;
    push word [bx]                                                 ;
    call print_hex_word                                            ;
    add ecx, 2                                                     ;
                                                                   ;
    cmp word [bx], 0xFFFF                                          ;
    je .done                                                       ;
                                                                   ; 
    jmp .loop1                                                     ;
.done:                                                             ;
    mov bx, done_msg                                               ;
    call print_string                                              ;
    ret                                                            ;
;------------------------------------------------------------------;
```

[image: Output 2]

But while testing the code to see what is wrong I stumbled upon another problem. I call the ListModes function as follows:

```
; Set Video Mode -------------------;
                                        ;
    mov ax, 0                           ;
    mov es, ax                          ;
    mov ax, vbe_info_structure          ;
    mov di, ax                          ;
                                        ;
    mov ax, 0x4F00                      ;
                                        ;
    int 0x10                            ;
                                        ;
    cmp ax, 0x004F                      ;
    jne Video_Error                     ;
                                        ;
    call ListModes                      ;
```

After doing some testing I noticed that nothing after this line gets executed, I tried setting the video mode to something else, tried printing some string and etc. calling ListModes seems to lock up or loop.

Edit 2: The entire code

```
[ORG 0x7e00]
BITS 16

global _SecondStage

_SecondStage:
    
    ; Lets take the drive number -------;
    mov [dev], dl                       ;
    ; ----------------------------------;
    
    ; Inform that Bootloader is gone ---;
    mov bx, WelcomeMessage              ;
    call print_string                   ;
    ; ----------------------------------;
    
    ; Load the Rest of the kernel-------;
    ; Adress on RAM ----;               ;
    mov ax, 0           ;               ;
    mov es, ax          ;               ;
    mov bx, 0x1000      ;               ;
    ; ------------------;               ;
                                        ;
    ; Disk Read Int ----;               ;-----------------------------------------------------------------;
    mov ah, 0x02        ; BIOS Command                                                                    ;
    mov al, 1           ; Number of Sectors to read                                                       ;
    mov ch, 0x00        ; Low Eight bit of cylinder number                                                ;
    mov cl, 0x06        ; 0-5 bits sector number to start from 6-7 bits high two bits of cylinder number  ;
    mov dh, 0x00        ; Head Number                                                                     ;
    mov dl, [dev]       ; Drive Number                                                                    ;
    int 13h             ;               ;-----------------------------------------------------------------;
    ; ------------------;               ;
                                        ;
    ; Disk Errors ------;               ;
    jc disk_error       ;               ;
    ; ------------------;               ;
    ; ----------------------------------;
    
    ; Set Video Mode -------------------;
                                        ;
    mov ax, 0                           ;
    mov es, ax                          ;
    mov ax, vbe_info_structure          ;
    mov di, ax                          ;
                                        ;
    mov ax, 0x4F00                      ;
                                        ;
    int 0x10                            ;
                                        ;
    cmp ax, 0x004F                      ;
    jne Video_Error                     ;
                                        ;
    call ListModes                      ;
                                        ;
                                        ;
                                        ;
    mov ax, 0x4F02                      ;     I added these lines to test if something executes after ListMode
    mov bx, 11Bh | 0x4000               ;     It seems that nothing is executed the output is the same as the output 2 image, the expected output is a blank screen 
                                        ;
    int 0x10                            ;
    ; ----------------------------------;   

    
    ; Go 32 Bit ------------------------;
    jmp Start32                         ;
    ; ----------------------------------;
    
    ; Error when Getting VBE_INFO-------;
Video_Error:                            ;
                                        ;
    mov bx, video_error_msg             ;
    call print_string                   ;
                                        ;
    jmp $                               ;
                                        ;
    ; ----------------------------------;
    
Start32:
    
    ; Load GDT--------------------------;
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]               ;
                                        ;
    cli                                 ;
    ; ----------------------------------;
    
    ; Enable Protected Mode-------------;
    mov eax , cr0                       ; To make the switch to protected mode , we set
    or eax , 0x1                        ; the first bit of CR0 , a control register
    mov cr0 , eax                       ; Update the control register
    ; ----------------------------------;

    ; Far Jump--------------------------;
    jmp CODE_SEG:Bit32                  ;
    ; ----------------------------------;
    
    jmp $
    
    
; Definitions -------------;
                           ;
disk_error:                ;
    mov bx, disk_error_msg ;
    call print_string      ;
    jmp $                  ;
; -------------------------;

; 16 Bit Print ------------;
print_string:              ;
                           ;    
.loop:                     ;
    mov al,[bx]            ; 
    cmp al,0               ;
    je return              ;
    push bx                ;
    mov ah,0Eh             ;
                           ;
    int 10h                ;
    pop bx                 ;
    inc bx                 ;
    jmp .loop              ;
                           ;
return:                    ;
    ret                    ;
; -------------------------;

; 16 Bit Print Hex--;
print_hex_word:     ;
    push bp         ;
    mov bp, sp      ; BP=SP, on 8086 can't use sp in memory operand
    push dx         ; Save all registers we clobber
    push cx         ;
    push bx         ;
    push ax         ;
                    ;
    mov cx, 0x0404  ; CH = number of nibbles to process = 4 (4*4=16 bits)
                    ; CL = Number of bits to rotate each iteration = 4 (a nibble)
    mov dx, [bp+4]  ; DX = word parameter on stack at [bp+4] to print
    mov bx, [bp+6]  ; BX = page / foreground attr is at [bp+6]
                    ;
.loop:              ;
    rol dx, cl      ; Roll 4 bits left. Lower nibble is value to print
    mov ax, 0x0e0f  ; AH=0E (BIOS tty print),AL=mask to get lower nibble
    and al, dl      ; AL=copy of lower nibble
    add al, 0x90    ; Work as if we are packed BCD
    daa             ; Decimal adjust after add.
                    ;    If nibble in AL was between 0 and 9, then CF=0 and
                    ;    AL=0x90 to 0x99
                    ;    If nibble in AL was between A and F, then CF=1 and
                    ;    AL=0x00 to 0x05
    adc al, 0x40    ; AL=0xD0 to 0xD9
                    ; or AL=0x41 to 0x46
    daa             ; AL=0x30 to 0x39 (ASCII '0' to '9')
                    ; or AL=0x41 to 0x46 (ASCII 'A' to 'F')
    int 0x10        ; Print ASCII character in AL
    dec ch          ;
    jnz .loop       ; Go back if more nibbles to process
                    ;
    mov al, ' '     ;##############################################     
    int 10h         ;##############################################
    pop ax          ; Restore registers
    pop bx          ;
    pop cx          ;
    pop dx          ;
    pop bp          ;
    ret             ;
; ------------------;


; Video List ------------------------------------------------------;
ListModes:                                                         ;
                                                                   ;
    mov ecx, 0                                                     ;
.loop1:                                                            ;
                                                                   ;
    mov ax, vbe_info_structure+0x0E                                ;
    add ax, cx                                                     ;
    mov bx, ax                                                     ;
    push word [bx]                                                 ;
    call print_hex_word                                            ;
    add ecx, 2                                                     ;
                                                                   ;
    cmp word [bx], 0xFFFF                                          ;
    je .done                                                       ;
                                                                   ; 
    jmp .loop1                                                     ;
.done:                                                             ;
    mov bx, done_msg                                               ;
    call print_string                                              ;
    ret                                                            ;
;------------------------------------------------------------------;


; Variables -------------------------------------------------------------;
WelcomeMessage db "Second Stage Bootloader taking over...",13,10,0       ;
disk_error_msg db "Disk Error",13,10,0                                   ;
dev: db 0                                                                ;
video_error_msg db "Cannot retrieve video information",13,10,0           ;
done_msg db "Done",13,10,0                                               ;
space_msg db " ",0                                                       ;
vbe_info_structure:                                                      ;
    .signature db "VBE2"    ; indicate support for VBE 2.0+              ;
    .table_data: resb 512-4 ; reserve space for the table below          ;
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------;

[BITS 32]                  ; We are now in 32 bit   

Bit32:
    
    mov ax , DATA_SEG
    mov ds , ax 
    mov ss , ax 
    mov es , ax
    mov fs , ax
    mov gs , ax

    mov ebp , 0x90000 
    mov esp , ebp

    ;call 0x1000


    jmp $

; GDT -------------------------------------------------------------------;
gdt_start :                                                              ;
    gdt_null :                                                           ; the mandatory null descriptor
    dd 0x0                                                               ; 'dd ' means define double word ( i.e. 4 bytes )
    dd 0x0                                                               ;
    gdt_code :                                                           ;
    dw 0xffff                                                            ; Limit ( bits 0 -15)
    dw 0x0                                                               ; Base ( bits 0 -15)
    db 0x0                                                               ; Base ( bits 16 -23)
    db 10011010b                                                         ; 1st flags , type flags
    db 11001111b                                                         ; 2nd flags , Limit ( bits 16 -19)
    db 0x0                                                               ; Base ( bits 24 -31)
    gdt_data :                                                           ;
    dw 0xffff                                                            ; Limit ( bits 0 -15)
    dw 0x0                                                               ; Base ( bits 0 -15)
    db 0x0                                                               ; Base ( bits 16 -23)
    db 10010010b                                                         ; 1st flags , type flags
    db 11001111b                                                         ; 2nd flags , Limit ( bits 16 -19)
    db 0x0                                                               ; Base ( bits 24 -31)
gdt_end :                                                                ;
                                                                         ;
gdt_descriptor :                                                         ;
dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1                                               ;
dd gdt_start                                                             ;
                                                                         ;
CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start                                        ;
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start                                        ;
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------;

; Padding -----------------;
times 2048-($-$$) db 0     ;
; -------------------------;

times 512 db 0xab          ; disk padding so that disk loader doesn't get angry
```

Comment: Did you notice the pattern in your WORDs? `aabb ccaa ddcc eecc ...` :) You are incrementing `ecx` by one but a WORD is two bytes. Besides that, do you want to avoid using the VBE? Using VBE is slower than programming the hardware, but programming the hardware is hard because graphic cards have not been standardized and are a huge topic.

Comment: @MargaretBloom good catch on aabb stuff, thanks. What do you mean "do you want to avoid using VBE?" Am I not using VBE already?

Comment: @MargaretBloom can you also check the edit?

Comment: I was under the impression you were asking for a faster way and skipping the VBE would be faster but pretty much insane. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Regarding the "lock-up", do `ListModes` have a `ret`?

Comment: @MargaretBloom No, I would never think of skipping VBE. Yes ListModes does have a ret but it seems to not return, any code that follow it isn't being executed.

Comment: You need to make a [mcve] or it will be hard to pin down the problem. For example, does `print_hex_word` clean the stack (i.e. uses `ret 02h`)?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I added the entire file as a ugly code block as a edit.

Comment: Try adding `add sp, 2` before `add ecx, 2`. `print_hex_word` doesn't remove its parameter from the stack, the `add sp, 2` should do it.

Comment: @MargaretBloom It miraculously did work! Thank you. May I ask the reason behind the addition of ```add sp, 2```

Comment: Just like @MargaretBloom said, you have a `push word [bx]` before your call to `print_hex_word`, and no corresponding `pop`, so the stack is out of balance and keeps growing till it overflows.  `add sp, 2` effectively discards what was pushed; it's like a `pop` that doesn't write the value to any register.  It will make sense if you think about what `push/pop` actually do.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you!